# saving webcam image to a website

Tags: actionscript-3

How can i save a webcam screenshot to a website?

I know you can save it to your hard drive using:

```
var browseFileReference = new FileReference();
        browseFileReference.save(video);
```

But how would i go about it to save this image to a website, lets say flickr or facebook or something.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at existing AS3 library.

Flickr : http://code.google.com/p/as3flickrlib/

Facebook : http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook.html

Answer (score 0):

The basic steps are, generate the bitmap data for the region you want, use one of the F/OSS libraries to generate PNG or JPEG data, base64 the data, and then generate a URLRequest with the encoded image as POST data, which can hen be handled server side.  I would have to dig through projects to find the proper classes I have to do this to show a real example, but this is actually really simple.  Each of the steps I outline can be implemented in a few lines of code using existing libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the screenshot of the webcam as ByteArray. Make sure you have the JPGEncoder class (from the as3corelib).

```
        // bitmapdata
        var btmData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(video.width, video.height);
        btmData.draw(video);

        // make jpg
        var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(90);
        var jpgBytes:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(btmData);
```

Now, you can use the as3flickrlib to connect with Flickr. Danny Patterson wrote a nice article to upload a ByteArray to Flickr with this library, see http://blog.dannypatterson.net/2009/08/upload-bytearray-to-flickr/

Edit: I would first try to upload it to Facebook, that is much easier than uploading an image to Flickr.